# QGLWidget with 2 rendering mode

Tags: qt, opengl, opencv, qglwidget

I have an OpenGL widget in Qt (inherits from QGLWidget), with 2 rendering mode :

1. rendering default cube (`#define CUBE_MODE 0`).
2. rendering opencv image (`#define IMAGE_MODE 1`).

I have a public method to set which mode to be rendered (`void setRenderMode(int mode)`).
I have also a combo box which contains 2 items : Cube and Image.

I want that when I click on an item in combo box (for example cube), the openGL widget shows the cube, and when I click on the other item (image), the widget shows the image. So I used the slot/signal system to do that.

The window starts correctly, and shows the cube, but when I switch to image, the widget doesn't show the image and when I try to return to cube item, it does'nt. (The 2 modes work correctly when I used them separately without the combo box).

Here is a snippet of my code :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui -> setupUi(this);

openglWidget = new GLWidget();
openglWidget->setRenderMode(0);


ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(openglWidget);

connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(showModel(int)));

}

void MainWindow::showModel(int index)
{
switch(index)
{
case 0:
    openglWidget->setRenderMode(0);     
    break;

case 1:
    openglWidget->setRenderMode(1);

    break;
}
}
```

the paintGL method is :

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{

makeCurrent();

if( !mSceneChanged )
    return;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

switch( mPaintMode )
{
case POINT_CLOUD_MODE:
{
    renderPointCloud();
}
break;

case IMAGE_MODE:
    renderImage();
    break;

default:
    renderDefaultCube();
}

}
```

**Update**

rendering the image code :

```
void GLWidget::renderImage()
{
makeCurrent();

glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

if (!mImage.isNull())
{
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    {
        int imW = mImage.width();
        int imH = mImage.height();

        bool resized = false;

        if( imW != this->size().width() &&
                imH != this->size().height() )
        {
            mImage = mImage.scaled( this->size(),
                                    Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                    Qt::FastTransformation );

            resized = true;
        }

        //Centering image in draw area
        int posX = (this->size().width()-imW)/2;
        int posY = (this->size().height()-imH)/2;

        glRasterPos2i( posX, posY );
        //Centering image in draw area

        glDrawPixels( mImage.width(), mImage.height(),
                      GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mImage.bits());

        if( resized)
        {
            imW = mImage.width();
            imH = mImage.height();


        }
    }
    glPopMatrix();


    glFlush();
}

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

}
```

and the setFrame method:

```
void GLWidget::setFrameImage(Mat img )
{
if( !img.data )
{
    qDebug( "Warning: No Image to be set");
    return;
}

if( img.channels() == 3)
    mImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(img.data), img.cols, img.rows,
                    img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
else if( img.channels() == 1)
    mImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(img.data), img.cols, img.rows,
                    img.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
else
    return;

mImage = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(mImage);

mSceneChanged = true;

updateGL();
}
```

**Update #2**

I modified paintGL to that :

```
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{

makeCurrent();

if( !mSceneChanged )
return;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

switch( mPaintMode )
{
case CUBE_MODE:
{
renderDefaultCube();
}
break;

case IMAGE_MODE:
renderImage();
break;


}

}
```

When I set openglWidget -> setRenderMode(0); I can see only the cube but when I click on Image item on combo box i can't see anything and vice versa when I set openglWidget -> setRenderMode(1).

**Update #3** :  The full source code

**GLWidget.h**

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL>

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>


#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include "rk_geometry.h"



 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;


 #define CUBE_MODE 0
 #define IMAGE_MODE 1

 #define PLANE_XY 0
 #define PLANE_XZ 1
 #define PLANE_YZ 2


 class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
 {
 Q_OBJECT

 public:
 GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);



 protected:
 void        initializeGL(); 
 void        paintGL(); 
 void        mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);    
 void        mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);     
 void        keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event );    
 void        resizeGL(int width, int height);        


 void        renderImage();          
 void        renderDefaultCube();    

 private:
 void        drawAxis();     
 void        drawGridXY();  
 void        drawGridXZ();  
 void        drawGridYZ();   
 void        drawCameraTargetSphere(); 
 void        drawCloudBox( cloud_rgb_t::Ptr cloud, int r, int g, int b);



 public slots:
 void        doPitch(double angle);  
 void        doRoll(double angle);  
 void        doYaw(double angle);   

 void        updateScene(); 

 void        setRenderMode( int renderMode );    

 void        setFrameImage( Mat img );

 void        resetView( bool update=false );
 void        topView(); 

 bool        showCameraTarget( bool show=true);      
 bool        showGrid( int idx, bool show=true );    
 bool        showBoxes(bool show=true);              



 private:
 float       mZoom;                 

 rkGeom::CPoint position;            
 rkGeom::CVector forward;           
 rkGeom::CVector up;                 
 rkGeom::CVector right;              

 int         mPtSize;               

 QColor      qtBlack;              

 QPoint      lastPos;                



 bool        mShowGrid[3];          
 bool        mDrawBoxes;             

 int         mPaintMode;            

 QImage      mImage;                 


 bool        mShowCameraTarget;    





 };
```

**GLWidget.cpp**

```
  #include "GLWidget.h"



    #define MIN_CAM_DIST 0.25f  
    #define MOV_STEP     0.05f  

    GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent),
    position(0,0,0),
    forward(0, 0, -1),
    up(0, 1, 0),
    right(1, 0, 0)
    {
    mZoom = MIN_CAM_DIST;
    mDrawBoxes = false;

    qtBlack = QColor::fromRgb(0, 0, 0);


    mPaintMode = -1;

    setFocusPolicy( Qt::ClickFocus );

    mShowCameraTarget = true;

    mPtSize = 1;

    mShowGrid[0] = true;
    mShowGrid[1] = false;
    mShowGrid[2] = false;

    resetView(false);
    }


    void GLWidget::initializeGL()
    {

    makeCurrent();
    qglClearColor(qtBlack.darker());

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);


    }

    void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
    {

    makeCurrent();
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    if( mPaintMode == CUBE_MODE )
        gluPerspective( 60.0, double(width)/height, 0.01, 200000 );
    else if( mPaintMode == IMAGE_MODE )
        glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 0, 1);     



    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    }

    void GLWidget::paintGL()
    {

    makeCurrent();


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    switch( mPaintMode )
    {
    case CUBE_MODE:
    {

        renderDefaultCube();
    }
    break;

    case IMAGE_MODE:
        renderImage();
        break;


    }

    }

    void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
    if( mPaintMode == IMAGE_MODE )
        return;

    lastPos = event->pos();
    }

    void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
    if( mPaintMode == IMAGE_MODE )
        return;

    float dx = (float)(event->x() - lastPos.x());
    float dy = (float)(event->y() - lastPos.y());


    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        doPitch( DEG2RAD(dy));
        doYaw( DEG2RAD(-dx));

        updateGL();
    }
    else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton)
    {

        mZoom += dx*0.1;

        if( mZoom < MIN_CAM_DIST )
            mZoom = MIN_CAM_DIST;

        updateGL();
    }

    else if (event ->buttons() & Qt::MidButton)
    {
        if (dx > 0)
            position.z += 100;

        if (dx < 0)
            position.z -= 100;



        updateGL();
    }

    lastPos = event->pos();
    }

    void GLWidget::keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event )
    {
    float dx, dy, dz;
    dx = dy = dz = 0.0f;



    if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_A ) 
    {
        doRoll(DEG2RAD(1));
    } else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_D ) 
    {
        doRoll(DEG2RAD(-1));
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_Up ) 
    {
        position += MOV_STEP*forward;
    }else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_Down ) 
    {
        position -= MOV_STEP*forward;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_Left ) 
    {
        position -= MOV_STEP*right;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_Right ) 
    {
        position += MOV_STEP*right;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_Home ) 
    {
        position.z += MOV_STEP;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_End )
    {
        position.z -= MOV_STEP;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_PageUp )
    {
        position.y += MOV_STEP;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_PageDown )
    {
        position.y -= MOV_STEP;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_Minus ) 
    {
        mPtSize--;
        if( mPtSize<1 )
            mPtSize=1;
    }
    else if ( event->key() == Qt::Key_Plus ) 
    {
        mPtSize++;
        if( mPtSize>10 )
            mPtSize=10;
    }

    updateGL();
    }

    void GLWidget::doPitch(double angle)
    {
    forward = unit(forward * cos(angle) + up * sin(angle));
    up = right.cross(forward);
    }

    void GLWidget::doRoll(double angle)
    {
    right = unit(right * cos(angle) + up * sin(angle));
    up = right.cross(forward);
    }

    void GLWidget::doYaw(double angle)
    {
    right = unit(right * cos(angle) + forward * sin(angle));
    forward = up.cross(right);
    }

void GLWidget::updateScene()
{
    if( this->isVisible() )
        updateGL();
}

void GLWidget::setRenderMode( int renderMode )
{
    mPaintMode = renderMode;
    updateGL();
}

void GLWidget::renderDefaultCube()
{
    makeCurrent();


    static const int coords[5][4][3] =
    {
        { { +1, -1, -1 }, { -1, -1, -1 }, { -1, +1, -1 }, { +1, +1, -1 } },
        { { +1, -1,  0 }, { -1, -1,  0 }, { -1, +1,  0 }, { +1, +1,  0 } },
        { { +1, -1, +1 }, { -1, -1, +1 }, { -1, +1, +1 }, { +1, +1, +1 } },
        { {  0, -1, -1 }, { +1,  0, -1 }, {  0, +1, -1 }, { -1,  0, -1 } },
        { {  0, -1, +1 }, { +1,  0, +1 }, {  0, +1, +1 }, { -1,  0, +1 } }
    };

    glPointSize(mPtSize);


    glScalef(0.01f,0.01f,0.01f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();


    gluLookAt(  position.x-mZoom*forward.i, position.y-mZoom*forward.j, position.z-mZoom*forward.k,
                position.x, position.y, position.z,
                up.i, up.j, up.k);


    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3ub( 0, 255, 0 );

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            glVertex3d(coords[i][j][0], coords[i][j][1], coords[i][j][2]);
        }

    }
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

    glPointSize(mPtSize);



}


void GLWidget::drawCameraTargetSphere()
{
    glColor4f( 0.8,0.8,0.8,0.3);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef( position.x, position.y, position.z );
    static GLUquadric* quad = gluNewQuadric();

    gluSphere( quad, 0.025f, 16, 16 );
    glPopMatrix();
}


void GLWidget::renderImage()
{
    makeCurrent();

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if (!mImage.isNull())
    {
        glLoadIdentity();

        glPushMatrix();
        {
            int imW = mImage.width();
            int imH = mImage.height();

            bool resized = false;

            if( imW != this->size().width() &&
                    imH != this->size().height() )
            {
                mImage = mImage.scaled( this->size(),
                                        Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                        Qt::FastTransformation );

                resized = true;
            }


            int posX = (this->size().width()-imW)/2;
            int posY = (this->size().height()-imH)/2;

            glRasterPos2i( posX, posY );


            glDrawPixels( mImage.width(), mImage.height(),
                          GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mImage.bits());

            if( resized)
            {
                imW = mImage.width();
                imH = mImage.height();


            }
        }
        glPopMatrix();


        glFlush();
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);



}

void GLWidget::setFrameImage(Mat img )
{
    if( !img.data )
    {
        qDebug( "Warning: No Image to be set");
        return;
    }

    if( img.channels() == 3)
        mImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(img.data), img.cols, img.rows,
                        img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    else if( img.channels() == 1)
        mImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(img.data), img.cols, img.rows,
                        img.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    else
        return;

    mImage = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(mImage);



    updateGL();
}



void GLWidget::resetView( bool update )
{
    position.x = -0.311778;
    position.y = 0.242323;
    position.z = 0.441647;

    forward.i = 0.284576;
    forward.j = -0.414646;
    forward.k = 0.864341;

    up.i = -0.020237;
    up.j = -0.904017;
    up.k = -0.427017;

    right.i = 0.95844;
    right.j = 0.104027;
    right.k = -0.265653;

    mZoom = MIN_CAM_DIST;


    if( update )
        updateGL();
}

void GLWidget::topView()
{
    position.x = position.y = 0;
    position.z = 5.0;

    forward.i = 0;
    forward.j = 0;
    forward.k = -1;
    up.i = 0;
    up.j = 1;
    up.k = 0;
    right.i = 1;
    right.j = 0;
    right.k = 0;

    mZoom = MIN_CAM_DIST;


    updateGL();
}

void GLWidget::drawAxis()
{
    float limit = 10.0f;
    float limitAxe = 0.3f;

    glLineWidth( 1.0 );
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    {

        glColor4f( 0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.5 );

        glVertex3f( -limit, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( limitAxe, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( limit, 0, 0 );

        glVertex3f( 0, -limit,  0 );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( 0, limitAxe, 0 );
        glVertex3f( 0, limit,  0 );

        glVertex3f( 0, 0, -limit );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, limitAxe );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, limit  );
    }
    glEnd();

    glLineWidth( 3.0 );
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    {

        glColor4f( 1.0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( limitAxe, 0, 0 );

        glColor4f( 0, 1.0, 0, 0.5 );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( 0, limitAxe, 0 );

        glColor4f( 0, 0, 1.0, 0.5 );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, 0 );
        glVertex3f( 0, 0, limitAxe );
    }
    glEnd();
}


void GLWidget::drawGridXY()
{
    float limit = 10.0f;
    float gridSize = 1.0f;

    glColor4f( 0.4,0.4,0.4,0.5);
    float x = -limit;
    float y = -limit;

    glLineWidth( 1.0 );

    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    {
        while( x<=limit )
        {
            while( y<=limit )
            {
                if( y!=0  )
                {
                    glVertex3f( -limit, y, 0  );
                    glVertex3f( limit, y, 0 );
                }

                y+=gridSize;
            }

            if( x!=0 )
            {
                glVertex3f( x, -limit, 0 );
                glVertex3f( x, limit, 0 );
            }

            x+=gridSize;
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}

void GLWidget::drawGridXZ()
{
    float limit = 10.0f;
    float gridSize = 1.0f;

    glColor4f( 0.4,0.4,0.4,0.5);
    float x = -limit;
    float z = -limit;

    glLineWidth( 1.0 );

    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    {
        while( x<=limit )
        {
            while( z<=limit )
            {
                if( z!=0  )
                {
                    glVertex3f( -limit, 0, z  );
                    glVertex3f( limit, 0, z );
                }

                z+=gridSize;
            }

            if( x!=0 )
            {
                glVertex3f( x, 0, -limit  );
                glVertex3f( x, 0, limit  );
            }

            x+=gridSize;
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}

void GLWidget::drawGridYZ()
{
    float limit = 10.0f;
    float gridSize = 1.0f;

    glColor4f( 0.4,0.4,0.4,0.5);
    float y = -limit;
    float z = -limit;

    glLineWidth( 1.0 );

    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    {
        while( y<=limit )
        {
            while( z<=limit )
            {
                if( z!=0  )
                {
                    glVertex3f( 0, -limit, z  );
                    glVertex3f( 0, limit, z );
                }

                z+=gridSize;
            }

            if( y!=0 )
            {
                glVertex3f( 0, y, -limit  );
                glVertex3f( 0, y, limit  );
            }

            y+=gridSize;
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}

bool GLWidget::showGrid( int idx, bool show )
{
    bool old = mShowGrid[idx];
    mShowGrid[idx] = show;

    updateGL();

    return old;
}

bool GLWidget::showCameraTarget( bool show )
{
    bool old=mShowCameraTarget;
    mShowCameraTarget = show;

    updateGL();

    return old;
}

bool GLWidget::showBoxes(bool show/*=true*/)
{
    bool old=mDrawBoxes;
    mDrawBoxes=show;

    updateGL();

    return old;
}
```

**rk_geometry.h**

```
#include <cmath>

namespace rkGeom
{

class CPoint;
class CVector;

inline bool equal(double x, double y, double epsilon = 0.000001) {
    return fabs(x - y) <= epsilon;
}

// A class for 3-D Vectors.
//
//   v.i, v.j, v.k              Components of vector v
//   Vector(i, j, k)            Construct from components
//   Vector(p)                  Construct from a point
//   u + v, u += v              Vector addition
//   u - v, u -= v              Vector subtraction
//   -v                         <0, 0, 0> - v
//   u.dot(v)                   Dot product of u and v
//   u.cross(v)                 Cross product of u and v
//   v * c, c * v, v *= c       Multiplication of a vector and a scalar
//   v / c, v /= c              Division of a vector by a scalar
//   v.magnitude()              The length of v
//   unit(v)                    The vector of length 1 in the direction of v
//   normalize(v)               Changes v to unit(v)
//   cosine(u, v)               The cosine of the angle from u to v


class CVector
{
public:
    double i, j, k;
    CVector(double i = 0, double j = 0, double k = 0): i(i), j(j), k(k) {}
    CVector(CPoint p);
    CVector operator +(CVector v) {return CVector(i + v.i, j + v.j, k + v.k);}
    CVector& operator +=(CVector v) {i += v.i; j += v.j; k += v.k; return *this;}
    CVector operator -(CVector v) {return CVector(i - v.i, j - v.j, k - v.k);}
    CVector& operator -=(CVector v) {i -= v.i; j -= v.j; k -= v.k; return *this;}
    CVector operator -() {return CVector(-i, -j, -k);}
    double dot(CVector v) {return i * v.i + j * v.j + k * v.k;}
    CVector cross(CVector);
    CVector operator *(double c) {return CVector(i * c, j * c, k * c);}
    friend CVector operator *(double c, CVector v) {return v * c;}
    CVector& operator *=(CVector v) {i *= v.i; j *= v.j; k *= v.k; return *this;}
    CVector operator /(double c) {return CVector(i / c, j / c, k / c);}
    CVector& operator /=(double c) {i /= c; j /= c; k /= c; return *this;}
    double magnitude() {return sqrt(this->dot(*this));}
    friend CVector unit(CVector v) {return v / v.magnitude();}
    friend void normalize(CVector& v) {v /= v.magnitude();}
    friend double cosine(CVector u, CVector v) {return unit(u).dot(unit(v));}

};

// A class for 3-D Points.
//
//   p.x, p.y, p.z              Components (coordinates) of point p
//   p + v, p += v              Add a point to a vector
//   p - q                      The vector from q to p
//   p.distanceTo(q)            The distance between p and q
//   p.distanceTo(P)            The distance between p and the plane P

class CPoint
{
public:
    double x, y, z;
    CPoint(double x = 0, double y = 0, double z = 0): x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    CPoint operator +(CVector v) {return CPoint(x + v.i, y + v.j, z + v.k);}
    CPoint& operator +=(CVector v) {x += v.i; y += v.j; z += v.k; return *this;}
    CPoint& operator -=(CVector v) {x -= v.i; y -= v.j; z -= v.k; return *this;}
    CVector operator -(CPoint p) {return CVector(x - p.x, y - p.y, z - p.z);}
    double distanceTo(CPoint p) {return (p - *this).magnitude();}

};



inline CVector::CVector(CPoint p): i(p.x), j(p.y), k(p.z) {
}

inline CVector CVector::cross(CVector v) {
    return CVector(j * v.k - k * v.j, k * v.i - i * v.k, i * v.j - j * v.i);
}

}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "GLWidget.h"

#include <math.h>


#include <QComboBox>




namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow :public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public :
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


    public slots :
    void showModel(int index);


    private :
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    GLWidget *openglWidget1;



};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui -> setupUi(this);

    openglWidget1 = new GLWidget();
    openglWidget1->setRenderMode(0);



    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(openglWidget1);

    connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(showModel(int)));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::showModel(int index)
{
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        {

        openglWidget1->setRenderMode(0);


        openglWidget1->updateGL();



        }
        break;

    case 1:
        {


        openglWidget1->setRenderMode(1);
        openglWidget1->setFrameImage(cv::imread("D:/Test switching/build/wireframe.jpg"));
        openglWidget1->updateGL();




        }
        break;
    }
}
```

**ui_mainwindow.h**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Start</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Cube</string>
       </property>
      </item>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Image</string>
       </property>
      </item>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;


    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and the **CMakeLists**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(test)

FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${QT_DEFINITIONS})

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

SET(test_HEADERS GLWidget.h mainWindow.h)
SET(test_SOURCES GLWidget.cpp mainwindow.cpp main.cpp)
SET(test_FORMS mainwindow.ui)

QT4_WRAP_UI(test_FORMS_HEADERS ${test_FORMS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(test_HEADERS_MOC ${test_HEADERS})
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test ${test_SOURCES} ${test_FORMS_HEADERS} ${test_HEADERS_MOC})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 1):

After changing the render mode call `updateGL` so that the window gets redrawn, reflecting the change of state.

#### Update

Also either set the QGLWidget to automatic buffer swap after return from paintGL or call SwapBuffers at the end of `paintGL` manually.

#### Update 2

This block in your paintGL

```
if( !mSceneChanged )
    return;
```

desn't belong there. A widget must be repaintend not only if the scene changed, but also after window resizes, if a window that was in front got moved away or if the window was minimized and then restored. When `paintGL` is called, then its for a reason, and that reason is, that things must be drawn. Cancelling this prematurely defies the purpose. So remove this test that doesn't belong there.

Comment: I just try to call openglWidget->updateGL(); after         OpenglWidget->setRenderMode(1); as you said and it still does not :(

Comment: @Amine: Could you please add the code of your `GLWidget::paintGL` method.

Comment: It's very long I can send it you in private message.

Comment: @Amine: It's not a problem if it's long. Posting lengthy code samples is perfectly acceptable on StackOverflow, heck it's even encouraged, instead of using pastebins or similar.

Comment: void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
 
    makeCurrent();

    if( !mSceneChanged )
        return;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    switch( mPaintMode )
    {
    case POINT_CLOUD_MODE:
    {
        renderPointCloud();
    }
    break;

    case IMAGE_MODE:
        renderImage();
        break;

    default:
        renderDefaultCube();
    }
  
}

Comment: @Amine: Well, I actually meant add it as an edit to your original question.

Comment: @Amine: Now seeing your code in a readable form I quickly found an serious issue. See my answer update.

Comment: I tried to add SwapBuffers at the end of paintGL but it still does'nt.

Comment: @Amine: Did you remove that `if(!mSceneChanged)return;` – if not yet, please do so.

Comment: I removed this line, the switching is working now, I can see the cube but I can't see the image.

Comment: @Amine: For that we need to see the code of `renderImage` and any code you use to load textures and such.

Comment: When I initialize the rendering mode in the default constructor (MainWindow) ui->openglWidget->setRenderMode(0) (The cube mode) I can see the cube but not the image when switching, and when I initialize it to image mode I can see only the image but not the cube when switching.

Comment: @Amine: Well, that you don't see the cube in image mode and vice versa is exactly what your code does. If you do want a different behavior then you must program it accordingly. In a switch statement the `default` case is reached only if none of the other cases is jumped to. So what exactly do you want? Seeing the cube and the image together in image mode and just the cube in cube mode? Or do you want to always see the image and the cube only in cube mode? If you want to see the cube all the time, then move `renderDefaultCube` out and after the switch block.

Comment: What I want is to see the cube in the cube mode and the image in the image mode. As I said, when I do openglWidget->setRenderMode(0) in the default constructor MainWindow, I can see the cube but when I switch to image item in combo box Ican't see the image and vice versa when I do : openglWidget ->setRenderMode(1). So I want that when I click on cube item to see the cube and when I click on image item to see the image.

Comment: @Amine: I hope it's just a mistake, but your modified `paintGL` again contains that `if(!mSceneChanged)return;` nonsense.

Comment: I removed mSceneChanged completely from my code, but it does'nt work. I think the problem comes from initializing. When I click on an item, the window should be reinitialize, the updateGL method has no effect.

Comment: Is there any method to reset the OpenGL context?

Comment: @Amine: Why would you want to reinitialize the context? Why would you reinitialize the window? All you have to do is change a variable and make the window redraw.

Comment: I did exactly what you said without success, the updateGL function has no effect.

Comment: @Amine: Could you please put your full source code somewhere, so that I can compile and run it myself?

Comment: @Amine: I'm currently looking at it. There are several issues besides your original one. For example the parameters for near and far in gluPerspective. You should choose near as large as possible, otherwise you're cramming all of the depth buffer resolution right into the very first 0.1 Z units. What you have in initializeGL actually belongs into paintGL and other things.

Comment: Thank you very much datenwolf, I'm just a beginner in OpenGL :).

Comment: @Amine: Another issue of your code is the constant rescaling of the image in drawImage. resizing an image is a potentially lossy operation, so what you do is, suboptimal. Also you shouldn't use glDrawPixels (it has been scrapped from OpenGL-3 and later altogether). Use a texture and a draw a textured quad. Also OpenGL will do the scaling for you then. Zooming you don't implement by moving the lookAt target point, but by varying the FOV of the perspective projection.

Comment: Thanks datenwolf I will do what you said. And for switching between image mode and cube mode, is there any suggestion?

Comment: @Amine: I don't think the switch by itself is the problem, but that you leave some stale OpenGL state around that messes with the rendering of one of them. In OpenGL you should always set state right when you need it, right before you need it. And you should make sure to disable and clean up state that might impair following steps. I suggest you completely remove all the code in initializeGL, resizeGL and paintGL and whatever is ultimately called from it. And then you try cleanly recreating the whole thing only starting from paintGL. Don't use initializeGL and resizeGL at first.